# Polygon boundary not adjacent after simplification

Tags: shapefile, simplify

I am  simplifying set of polygons that are adjacent. I used topologypreserveSimplifier which simplify each polygon separately the issue is the resulting polygons are not adjacent anymore.

[image]

After Simplification, there is gap coming between polygon , since they are part of different features. I have tried Vw, DP and Toplogical Simplifier. How can I merge polygon again ?

[image]

```
    public static SimpleFeatureCollection simplify(ShapefileDataStore mergedData, SimpleFeatureCollection collA,
            String attrName) throws IOException {
        Double tolerance = 0.003;
        SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(collA.getSchema());
        List<SimpleFeature> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());
            try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collA.features()) {
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
                        Geometry disGeom = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
                    if(disGeom == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Geometry g1 = TopologyPreservingSimplifier.simplify(disGeom, tolerance);
                    
                    builder.addAll(f.getAttributes());
                    String geomName = collA.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
                    builder.set(geomName, g1);
                    SimpleFeature fout = builder.buildFeature(null);
                    ret.add(fout);
                }
                itr.close();
            }
        return DataUtilities.collection(ret);
    }
```

Comment: Some ideas may be found from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407860/remove-slivers-gaps-generated-after-topologypreservesimplification.

Comment: If you are comfortable working in the database directly, you could try the postgis topology extension.

Comment: Remember the *topology* in `TopologyPreservingSimplifier` refers to the topology of the polygon not the layer as a whole

Comment: Yeah , you are right, it simplify the individual polygon, Now I am trying to implement the retain effective weightage area simplification(zhou jones) instead of VWlinesimplifier  which arcgis uses as one of simplification. I am stuck at how to calculate weightage area of triangle instead of min area.(https://1spatial.com/documentation/1generalise/Topics/Built-In%20Operations/Line_Simplification_Group.htm)