# Holes after topology simplification

Tags: shapefile, simplify

After applying the topology simplification mentioned in the answer
[Remove Slivers/Gaps generated after TopologyPreserveSimplification?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407860/remove-slivers-gaps-generated-after-topologypreservesimplification/408260#408260)
It is retaining the topology but is removing the polygon. Below is the image and sample shapefile data for the same (https://github.com/gizmogaurav/spatialPoc/blob/main/poc.zip)
Tolerance = .001

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you use this recipe? mapshaper can do the simplification https://mapshaper.org and you can tell it to preserver polygons while simplifying (no deletion)

Comment: I want to fully automate the process where manual intervention will not be involved , that's why I am trying to performed it using geotools in java and not wanted to use mapshaper, arcgis tools etc.

Comment: My code assumes that the polygons share a single line - if there are any gaps in the original polygons then they will remain (and probably grow) in the simplification process.

Comment: No, there is no gap in the original polygon. They are sharing the same line.  It is coming after simplification. I I shared the link for the original shape file in the question for the referenced.
https://github.com/gizmogaurav/spatialPoc/blob/main/poc.zip) Tolerance = .001

Comment: mapshaper have a command line e.g https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference so can be fully automated with it. For you Java solution, can't really help: not good enough with Java development

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell one of your polygons is "invalid" though QGis's validity checker disagrees with me.

[image]

As for why polygon 5 is not rebuilt, it seems to be related to the line in red which `Polygonizer` reports as a dangle. So again there may not be an exact match across those two polygons. Snapping to a grid might help but I haven't tried it.

[image]